# Why is wheat flour more popular than corn flour?

Tags: history, cornmeal

If I understand correctly, one of the major reasons that corn syrup is so popular is that it made corn syrup cheaper than sugar.  This makes sense to me.

However, it seems odd to me that this never really happened with corn flour/cornmeal vs wheat flour. While they definitely taste different, they still can often fill similar roles, and assuming that corn flour was cheaper, I'd expect it to gradually take over recipes in the US.

Was US-subsidized corn flour not cheaper than wheat flour?
Was there another reason corn flour didn't take over?

(I'm obviously not talking about countries south of the US, where corn is everywhere)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about the economics of food markets, and out of scope for the site.

Comment: Hi Nathan, we have never been able to take questions asking why a given culture prefers one foodstuff over another. This is a very complex matter, and while it is fun speculating about it, the SE voting mechanism hides that nobody of the people who answers and reads knows the true reasons.

Comment: @rumtscho perhaps consider updating your Help Center?  I'm not sure how common this sort of question is, but your Help Center definitely lists it as an on-topic question.

Comment: That's interesting, the Help center text is intended to exclude it - apparently it is not formulated well. Which part did read for you as including that question? We should probably change it to be more clear. The intention is that it is one of many types of question which fall under the off-topic reason of "Questions about food in general, but not about its preparation", maybe we could make a separate bullet point to be more clear.

Comment: I thought it was allowed because "The history of food and cooking" was allowed.  I still feel like there are historical events that have decided what people cook and eat (For example, indian trade brought in many spices, which changed how people cooked).  So, I'm not really sure how to differentiate that and my question.

Comment: More thoughts:  Perhaps "popular" was the wrong word.  I wasn't trying to get at "why do people like these flavors better", but it was more "why didn't the economics work out in this situation".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They are functionally quite different.  Corn flour does not contain gluten, so is not useful as a direct substitute. It has little to nothing to do with cost.

Comment: Ah, the absence of gluten makes a lot of sense.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

To some extent corn did replace wheat flour, for a while, and in a limited area (now Virginia, the Carolinas etc.).

Before cheap transportation within what's now the USA, [cornbread](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cornbread) was a way of using native American maize (and Native American methods) to make a substitute for European-style breads.

The thing is (and this comes back to moscafj's answer) that cornbread fulfils only some of the role of wheat bread - a cheap portable source of carbohydrate, which is also quite easy to prepare.  It's less robust (compared to a loaf used as a bread bowl, or a sop, for example).

Water and later especially rail transport of wheat grown in the Great Plains meant affordable wheat was available where maize was most consumed